# Export a vb.net list to excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, list, arraylist, export-to-excel

I have a list in vb.net, I need to know how to export this list to excel, It only have to show only 11 columns and the numbers of rows changes in every product
im trying it but its not working. 
this is my code

```
    Dim objApp As Excel.Application
    Dim objBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objBooks As Excel.Workbooks
    Dim objSheets As Excel.Sheets
    Dim objSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Excel.Range
    Dim StartRow, StartCol

    objApp = New Excel.Application()
    objBooks = objApp.Workbooks
    objBook = objBooks.Add
    objSheets = objBook.Worksheets
    objSheet = objSheets(1)

    listaReporte = ProcesarKardex()

    'this is my list
  selectedValues = listaReporte.OrderBy(Function(x)x.fechaOperacion).ToList())

   StartRow = 1
    StartCol = 1

   'write array as a row
    With objSheet
        Rng = .Range(.Cells(StartRow, StartCol),
            .Cells(UBound(selectedValues.ToArray, 1) - LBound(selectedValues.ToArray, 1) + StartRow,
            UBound(selectedValues.ToArray, 2) - LBound(selectedValues.ToArray, 2) + StartCol))
    End With
    Rng.Value = selectedValues ' Row

    'Write Array as a Column
    StartRow = 3
    StartCol = 1
    With objSheet
        Rng = .Range(.Cells(StartRow, StartCol),
            .Cells(UBound(selectedValues.ToArray, 1) - LBound(selectedValues.ToArray, 1) + StartRow,
            UBound(selectedValues.ToArray, 2) - LBound(selectedValues.ToArray, 2) + StartCol))
    End With
    Rng.Value = selectedValues.ToArray ' Column
```

it would be great if you could help me, thanks in advance!!

Comment: what's not working? does it error or what?

Comment: yes  its an error

Comment: I see you're using linq on listaReporte's fechaOperacion property, so I'm guessing that is a list of a custom class? You can't just write a list of custom class to a spreadsheet without looping through them somehow, or converting the list of classes to a multidimensional array and writing the array to the spreadsheet. Excel has no idea what to do with some custom class you're passing it